# Punch a hole into a texture in OpenGL ES 2.0 (Android)

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm drawing a background texture to the screen, and then a foreground texture, now i wan't to punch a hole into the foreground texture where the user touches the screen. The result should be the foreground texture with a hole, and through the hole you see the background texture. How do i achieve this via OpenGL ES 2.0. I know i can do it with canvas and PorterDuff, but this method is too slow for me.

Comment: Do you want to punch an arbitrary amount of holes, or just a single hole?

Comment: Do you want to edit the texture's image to include holes and reload the texture, or change the polygons to create holes and then reapply the original texture?

Comment: @Paul-Jan I wan't multitouch support, so not just a single hole

Comment: @mbeckish Is it possible with a fragment shader? The biggest problem is the speed, it should run on constantly 60 fps

Comment: @TEAM-ALPHA - Why don't you try something, and then post the code if you get stuck?

Comment: You're not being too specific about what specific effect you want, so there are a number of ways of going about this. Ultimately, you're going to need either transparency of some sort to be added to the foreground texture, and then blending to be enabled for your scene, or you're going to need to alter the geometry of the foreground object that your texture is drawn on.

Comment: i try building a custom shader